# More than one instance of mini_httpd

Tags: c, http

I am trying to run more than one instance of mini_httpd with a different port number in busybox in my device. But I am getting the following error.

> bind: Address already in use
>
> bind: Address already in use

the two config files are (for each of the instance I have used)
config file for the already running instance

```
data_dir=/var/www
#user=httpd
port=80
host=0.0.0.0
cgipat=**.cgi|**.php
#logfile=/var/log/mini_httpd
#pidfile=/var/run/mini_httpd.pid
charset=UTF-8
#ssl
certfile=/etc/minihttpd.pem
```

config file of the second instance which gives me error

```
    data_dir=/var/www
    #user=httpd
    port=8081
    host=0.0.0.0
    cgipat=**.cgi|**.php
    #logfile=/var/log/mini_httpd
    #pidfile=/var/run/mini_httpd.pid
    charset=UTF-8
    #ssl
    certfile=/etc/minihttpd.pem
```

Please help

Comment: Uh... those two config files look identical, including the port number.

Comment: Thanks for pointing. I had copied it wrongly. With different port numbers in config files, I am not able to launch the second instance of mini_httpd

Comment: Use `netstat -lpn` to see which program listens at each port.

Comment: I did that and no process is using the second port

Comment: I'd say comment in the log file setting, start the servers and inspect the logs.

Comment: Btw: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: You might like to shows how you start the servers.

Comment: So what happens if you start the second server first? What does netstat show in this case?

Comment: The PID file line is commented out so both instances will write to the same PID file? Maybe the error message is just misleading?

Comment: I tried two different pid files as mentioned by @Torp but still I get the same error. I invoke the process in the below mentioned way   /sbin/mini_httpd -r -u root -C mini.conf